# Silverlight Not Rendering Correctly When Hosted on IIS8

Tags: user-interface, iis, silverlight, configuration

We have an old legacy system written in silverlight 4.  i have been given the task of moving it from an old windows 2003 server to a windows 2012 server.

The software works perfectly whilst being run on IIS6.  On IIS8 the functionality id fine, but the UI is formatting incorrectly.  The interface stretches past the right side of the screen!

Now i'm thinking its some kind of setting, but after hours of searching the web I've found nothing on the subject.

Id be extremely grateful for and help.

Comment: Did you see any error message in web browser developer tool console or network panel? Based on my understanding, web browser render the interface based on source files loaded from server side. So if we can find any error message, then we may know what's going on there.

Comment: Thats the thing.  There are no errors.  The code has been lifted directly of a 2003 server, no code changes made at all.  The software works perfectly on IIS6, but goes screwy on IIS8 using the same browser (IE11) on the same windows 10 pc.  As the  only thing that has changed is the version of IIS logically it has to be something to do with IIS

Comment: Would you mind to compare the network resources loaded from IIS 8 and IIS 6? If we can find the difference, we may find the solution. You can check content-type, URL, file size,etc... Of course, you could try to capture and analyze first chance exception for your web application with debug diagnostic tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your help.  i have got to the bottom of the problem.  its one of the joys of working with legacy systems where everyone involved has left!!

The site needs to be set to run in Document Compatibility mode for - wait for it - IE5.

Putting the right HTTP Response header in did the trick.